# I'm moving hosting to a new platform, but mail is hosted elsewhere, will mail requests fail to resolve during propagation?

Tags: dns

I'm currently moving sites to a new hosting platform. For some of these sites on our old hosting platform, we have A, CNAME, and/or MX records directing mail traffic to some other host (Gmail or other).

Here's my question:
If I have those A, CNAME, and MX records duplicated on the new hosting platform, update the registrar with the new DNS servers, and keep the site live on both hosting platforms during propagation, will there be any instances where mail requests won't get to the proper location?

I'm currently thinking there won't be any issues, due to the redundancy between both DNS servers, but I have to be 100% sure.

All help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had the opportunity to just attempt the previous scenario and find out if I was correct. I'll share it here as an answer just in case someone else ends up in the same situation.

Because of the redundancy between both sets of primary DNS's, there was no issue with the clients being able to access their email and send/receive messages.